# Would it be possible to create a new constraint "type" with python?

Tags: python, constraints

Obviously it is possible to add new mesh "type" with python in the list of create mesh. I think I read that it isn't possible to create a new "modifier" type with python. What about constraints type (like a 4th kind of "track to" for example)? Would this be possible to do in python and if yes where should I start to look at in the docs ?

Thx a lot,
Stan

Almost three years after ..., I was wondering if that is still the case ? Are we able to create new modifiers or constraints types with the python API in 2.78 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently we don't support Python constraints (though they were supported at one point in Blender 2.4x).

Comment: Thx! That is what I was afraid of ... I guess I will have to use handlers or dive into my own blender build then :D

Comment: Almost three years after ..., I was wondering if that is still the case ? Are we able to create new modifiers or constraints types with the python API in 2.78 ?

Comment: @StanPaillereau in 2.78 you can use app.handlers to do almost what ever you want. You can script your own constraint engine and expose it in UI or even with nodes. Only the performance hit is concern.

Comment: @Jerryno The performance part could be avoided by creating your own build and using C...