# SET visual transform?

Tags: python

Is there a way to set an object's visual transform via the API?

AFAIK there's no way to create [custom constraints](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/17823/would-it-be-possible-to-create-a-new-constraint-type-with-python), so I am writing a constraint-like operation using [depsgraph handlers](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.handlers.html).

For what I am doing, I wish to modify an object's [`matrix_world`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.matrix_world) property **without updating `location`, `rotation`, or `scale`**, just as constraints do, so I don't overwrite the object's user-specified [`matrix_basis`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.matrix_basis). Is this possible? Is there a workaround?

Naively assigning `obj.matrix_world = myNewMatrix` results in `obj.matrix_basis`, `obj.location`, `obj.rotation_euler`, and `obj.scale` all being updated.

**Edit:** Delta transforms are an option, but I don't want to commandeer a potentially user-defined property. For the same reason as not wanting to overwrite the base transform.

Comment: You may want to explore delta transforms which don't modify the base transform matrix

Comment: Thanks for pointing out delta transforms. I updated my question

Comment: Hmm, I don't think there's an easy way to do it with basic features then. Maybe a custom geometry nodes modifier ? Or using a parent object transform ?